# Let me (be) free/loose

Tags: ellipsis, linking-verbs, object-complements

Proceeding from the internet, I inferred the following thing:
**(1)** *Let me free*. — idiomatic
**(2)** *Let me be free*. — idiomatic
**(3)** *Let me loose*. — idiomatic
**(4)** *Let me be loose*. — unidiomatic

That is, "be" is optional with "free" but can't be used with "loose".
Although, in terms of grammar, as far as I understand, "free" and "loose" are adjectives here and all four phrases are grammatical.

Am I right that:
All four variants are grammatical and that (4) isn't used is just a matter of how people got used to speaking.

Am I right that:
(1) and (2) mean the same and (1) is just a variant of (2) after omitting "be" (ellipsis).
The same thing could be said about (3) and (4), if (4) would be idiomatic.

Comment: The adjective [loose](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loose) has various possible meanings, so it sounds odd to describe a person as _being_ loose; while _let loose_ has only one meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I advise OP not to bother with any of his suggestions. They're all [extremely uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Let%20me%20go%2CLet%20me%20free%2CLet%20me%20be%20free%2CLet%20me%20loose%2CLet%20me%20be%20loose&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) compared to ***Let me go**!...*

[image]

But it may be worth noting that ***Let me be free**!* normally implies the speaker seeks *(long-term) **freedom within society*** (it's the sort of thing a *slave* might say), whereas all the others (including ***Let me free**!*) primarily imply the speaker wishes to be released from *(temporary) **physical restraints*** (he's tied up, being gripped firmly by a captor, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

(1) is unlikely to be used. Instead, it would be "let me go" or "set me free". It's most likely to mean release me from temporary captivity.

(2) means let me be free in general — that is, to do whatever I want, whenever I want.

(3) would normally be a phrase implying "take all the psychological shackles off me and let me make my own judgements and decisions so I can really show you what I can do."

(4) is a bit weird in English. To be "loose" can either mean having diarrhea, or being sexually promiscuous, or not being honest (as in "loose with the truth"). It's not really a request to be let out of captivity.